# Transfer function of electrical circuit

Tags: transfer-function

I have a question about this circuit. How do I get the transfer function of a circuit with a diode? The current through diode is $$I_d = e^{U_d/5} -1$$
[image]

Comment: The diode along with C2 are forming a peak detection circuit, such that the output will be a DC level approximating a recent peak on the input.  Since there's no load, only the diode's reverse leakage will discharge C2.  Hope it helps...I don't know what course or book this is for, so not sure what type of analysis to focus on.

Comment: Do you want the small-signal equivalent frequency response function, or just the DC (low-frequency) input-output transfer function? You won't be able to determine both simultaneously because the FRF changes depending on what the DC-input signal is.

Answer (score 3):

The requirement of linearity fails for a diode (i.e., \$f(ax)\ne a f(x)\$ for \$a<0\$), and thus the traditional definition of "transfer function" carries little meaning.  The best you can do is come up with a mathematical expression for the output.

Answer (score 1):

Well, we have the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWirl2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If we assume that all the initial conditions are equal to \$0\$ (so the circuit is at rest before \$t=0\$) than we can analyze this circuit using [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform). So we can write:

$$\text{v}_\text{in}\left(\text{s}\right)=\text{i}_\text{in}\left(\text{s}\right)\cdot\left(\text{Ls}+\frac{\text{R}}{1+\text{CRs}}\right)\tag1$$

Now, we know that:

$$\text{V}_\text{in}\left(t\right)=\hat{\text{u}}_\text{in}\sin\left(\omega t\right)\tag2$$

So:

$$\text{v}_\text{in}\left(\text{s}\right)=\frac{\hat{\text{u}}_\text{in}\omega}{\text{s}^2+\omega^2}\tag3$$

Now, the current through the resistor is given by:

$$\text{i}_\text{R}\left(\text{s}\right)=\frac{1}{1+\text{CRs}}\cdot\text{i}_\text{in}\left(\text{s}\right)\tag4$$

The voltage across the resistor is given by:

$$\text{v}_\text{R}\left(\text{s}\right)=\text{i}_\text{R}\left(\text{s}\right)\cdot\text{R}\tag5$$

Using all the equations from above we get:

$$\text{v}_\text{R}\left(\text{s}\right)=\frac{\hat{\text{u}}_\text{in}\omega}{\text{s}^2+\omega^2}\cdot\frac{\text{R}}{\text{CLRs}^2+\text{Ls}+\text{R}}\tag6$$

Now, as [@CristobolPolychronopolis](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/188304/cristobol-polychronopolis) commented, the capacitor after the diode will (ideally) charge until the top of the voltage across the resistor. So, we need to find the value of \$t\$ when \$\text{V}_\text{R}\left(t\right)\$ reaches a maximum the first time (and the value of that maximum). Now, we can find that point using the derivative.